# How to execute a controller file using shell_exec in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, controllers, shell

I want to create product using controller so how would i hit the controller using shell_exec.

How would i do that ?

My controller file is

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
protected $_pageFactory;
private $scopeConfig;
protected $_productCollectionFactory;
private $productAction;
protected $_dir;
protected $productFactory;
protected $productRepository;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $dir,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterfaceFactory $productFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory
    )
{
    $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
    $this->_dir = $dir;
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
  try {
    $product = $this->productFactory->create();
    $product->setSku('sku2');
    $product->setName('Product Name2');
    $product->setDescription("Product Description1");
    $product->setShortDescription("Product Short Description1");
    $product->setWebsiteIds([1]);
    $categories = ["3"]; //create an array of categories which you want to set for the product
    $product->setCategoryIds($categories);
    $product->setWeight(10);
    $product->setTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_SIMPLE);
    $product->setVisibility(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH); // To make product visible in both catalog,search
    $product->setPrice("100");
    $product->setAttributeSetId(4); // Attribute set for products
    $product->setStatus(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
    $product->setUrlKey("Product URL Key");
    $product->setStockData(
        array(
            'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
            'manage_stock' => 1,
            'is_in_stock' => 1,
            'qty' => 1
        )
    );
    $product = $this->productRepository->save($product);
    $product->save();
    } catch (Exception $e){
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
}
```

Actually i have text file( .txt ) which have multiple fields which is used to create product  so on hitting the controller directly it might be an issue ( ex. timeout or any other ) because some months ago ( i have worked on wordpress so there will be an timeout issue so there i have used shell and it solves that problem ) so, here i think it will create same issue while creating these product so i want to hit that using shell so the process is run on terminal.

Comment: Why do you wanna hit it from shell. Please provide complete use case.

Comment: Updated my use case in question please check @AbdulPathan

Comment: I assume there could be more than 1 product in your file which is making you think of timeout issue, which is correct. I would prefer to create a cron job which would read the file & create products.

Comment: I also thought about that but cron run at particular time on given time and i want to run that function on my button click or on my event and it is not run everyday so with using cron it will run at a given time @AbdulPathan

Comment: Do you upload a file from admin side ?

Comment: Means upload a file from admin didn't understand please give some details @AbdulPathan

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `shell_exec`, because it's dangerous.

I don't now what you are trying to achieve with your code, but you can create simple PHP script file for example in your root folder: `script/productImport.php`

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . './../app/bootstrap.php';

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

/* @var $indexController \Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Index\Index */
$indexController = $objectManager->get('Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Index\Index');

$indexController->execute();
```

Then you can run your script from CLI by using `php scripts/productsImport.php` - it will run code inside the `execute()` function.

Comment: Thanks for your response,
I have updated my use case in question please check @dudzio
Anyways liked your approach to that but i have a question is i have to run php command manually is it a way to hit that from Magento admin.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not completely understing your goal. The above code runs it in CLI, it doesn't use apach/nginx enginge to run the code, so timeouts - other than thos from MySQL will not affect it :)

Comment: Thanks for your response basically i want to create products from a text file so it has huge no. of data so my question is how do i run that script code from an event like click on a button.
Hope you understand
@Dudzio

Comment: I have added your code and run the command on terminal but it gives an error Could not open input file: scripts/productsImport.php please check @dudzio